# Why can I submit a transactionID with a transaction in hyperledger composer REST?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Composer REST server allows me to submit a transactionID with my transaction input.  The transaction is rejected if I supply a transactionID.  Is there a way to remove the field from the input so that the server ignores client submitted transaction id?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the explorer interface. The Rest Server is a Loopback application and so we are not able to hide these fields in the example section (see https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/663). An issue has been raised with Strongloop regarding this issue, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3510

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue till I started installing my hyperledger composer and fabric from scratch. That's when I realised that I had used a deprecated link for installing npm. I had encountered a bunch of errors that I had ignored.

following the steps given here worked for me, for installing npm correctly.
https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/
I also referred to https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html in case any command did not work.

after correct installation, you will be able to remove `transactionId` and `timestamp` without encountering any error.