# error executing hyperledger fabric code on localhost:3000 (through REST) - transactionId

Tags: localhost, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have tried executing a sample case of transfer of money between two accounts while referring to this:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-an-application-on-blockchain-using-hyperledger-3a83a80cbc71

I have executed all steps, from creating .bna and .card to installing them, starting the network etc.
On creating the RESTful API, I am able to see the blockchain on localhost:3000/explore.
I am also able to add customers and their linked account details.

However, while performing money transfer, there are two fields that are generated by default : transactionId and timestamp.

[screenshot showing 2 additional fields - timestamp and transactionId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAsLI.png)

It's the transactionId that is creating trouble. 
It does not allow me to leave it blank, or fill arbitrary values, or remove the field altogether.

[error when transactionId field is left blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B2T1.png)

**update**

Even after writing `"transactionId" : true` or `"transactionId" : false`, the problem persists.

Another user had encountered a similar problem. They fixed it by making their npm and node.js non-root. In my case, it is already non-root.
[it is non-root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DWCv.png)
Is it possible that npm and node.js are not installed properly? I had received a few errors during its installation [npm errors during installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzvKv.png)

Even after removing `transactionId` and `timestamp` fields, it doesn't work

[image: error after removing both fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transactionID (in the example) ideally should not appear in the **Swagger** example for the POST operations. That example is generated by the **LoopBack to Swagger** conversion that is done by LoopBack code (not Composer). You need to remove it (and the timestamp too ideally, as Composer will update its own) in your JSON.

see [Why can I submit a transactionID with a transaction in hyperledger composer REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001314/why-can-i-submit-a-transactionid-with-a-transaction-in-hyperledger-composer-rest) for an answer. This loopback/swagger issue was created against loopback - last issue created was  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3510

Comment: Thanks for the links, but the problem still persists, even after writing "transactionId" : false or "transactionId":true

Comment: hi there .. 1) did you read the instruction "You need to remove it" above in the answer? and 2) In your FIRST screenshot, your transaction would never work anyway - you need to supply it with the fully-qualified relationship - for 'from' and 'to' in the transaction. So an example is {
  "$class": "test.AccountTransfer",
  "from": "resource:test.Account#1",
  "to": "resource:test.Account#2",
  "amount": 10
}`  - I suggest if you have any more issues with the tutorial, to contact the author of that (its something someone shared personally, to the community at large). But the above, works.

Comment: I see you added an update about root vs non-root Composer install (not related to business network / REST issues you're having, which works anyway, because after all you created the assets and participants). The simplest way is to follow the instructions https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html which clearly states not to use sudo or root - and follow npm best practices here https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions and use a Node Version Manager to manage your node versions

Comment: 1) i did try removing the lines altogether, but it gave me error 500. 2) I know, i did rectify it later, by writing a fully qualified "to" and "from" referencing the account through its ID. it still did not work. Also, I did follow the instructions on the site, npm is non-root. but i had received too many errors then, could you please see if they are normal? The screenshot is URL-ed, "npm errors during installation"

Comment: judging by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626383/node-package-manager-got-corrupted-in-some-way-now-it-cannot-be-installed) link, your Node Package Manager could possibly be corrupted - there is some issue (outside of Composer, as you can appreciate) that is causing the errors posted in your screenshot

Comment: Thanks. the problem is resolved after installing npm correctly

Comment: I have no idea where to remove "it".

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem, after looking into it and spending lot of time. I found this is not the problem of **npm** and
**node.js**, if we are installing them as non root. This is the problem of Loopback so you have to make an API JSON request without
**"transactionId"** and **"timestamp"** means remove both of them.  It will work fine as loopback swagger will update it automatically.
I hope it will work for all, who are facing the same kind of problem.

Comment: how and where do you remove them? Like do something in my chaincode and redeploy?

Comment: @deltu100 When you fire an api request from swagger and as well as from postman.

Comment: aah oke, so basically ignore the addition of these attributes. I thought the rest server wouldnt like that