# Cannot Post Hyperledger Transaction on Rest API

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am having some trouble posting a transaction on my ReST server. When I try to POST a transaction, I always get a 422 error. If I delete any fields, I will get a 500 error. It seems like whatever transaction id is there is invalid, and I do not know why it is invalid. In my original .cto files, I did not ask for there to be a transactionID field, so I am assuming this is a default field. Here is a screenshot of my POST method:

[image: Post Method]

Here is my input that I put in:

```
{
  "$class": "models.transactionsModel.InvalidateCertificate",
  "certificate": "#cert2",
  "transactionId": "string",
  "timestamp": "2018-06-18T16:57:45.644Z"
}
```

I made the certificate identifiable by a hash string

Here is the resulting curl, body, and header respectively,

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "$class": "models.transactionsModel.InvalidateCertificate", \ 
   "certificate": "#cert2", \ 
   "transactionId": "string", \ 
   "timestamp": "2018-06-18T16:57:45.644Z" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:3000/api/models.transactionsModel.InvalidateCertificate'
```

---

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 422,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "The `models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate` instance is not valid. Details: `transactionId` can't be set (value: \"string\").",
    "details": {
      "context": "models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate",
      "codes": {
        "transactionId": [
          "absence"
        ]
      },
      "messages": {
        "transactionId": [
          "can't be set"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stack": "ValidationError: The `models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate` instance is not valid. Details: `transactionId` can't be set (value: \"string\").\n    at /Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:398:12\n    at models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate.<anonymous> (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:578:11)\n    at models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate.next (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:93:12)\n    at models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate.<anonymous> (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:575:23)\n    at models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate.trigger (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:83:12)\n    at models_transactionsModel_InvalidateCertificate.Validatable.isValid (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:541:8)\n    at /Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:394:9\n    at doNotify (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:178:5)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:153:8)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:176:15)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:153:8)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/Users/harshdeshpande/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:176:15)"
  }
}
```

---

```
{
  "date": "Mon, 18 Jun 2018 18:23:47 GMT",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "x-download-options": "noopen",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "vary": "Origin, Accept-Encoding",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}
```

What is even stranger is that I can submit a valid transaction via the Composer playground. In the composer playground, though, it does not ask for a transactionID or timestamp - it automatically generates while the transaction is being submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the **answer** here -> [error executing hyperledger fabric code on localhost:3000 (through REST) - transactionId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618081/error-executing-hyperledger-fabric-code-on-localhost3000-through-rest-trans) - it is really a Loopback issue.

Post your  same transaction as follows (but remove the transactionId and timestamp - these are generated for you and the former represents the transaction Id on the ledger):

```
{
  "$class": "models.transactionsModel.InvalidateCertificate",
  "certificate": "#cert2"
}
```

cheers

Comment: I tried this but now I am getting an error 500: FQN is invalid.

Comment: hello, I am guessing your `certificate` field is a relationship field - can you post your model for this transaction? Its likely its meant to be something like  "resource:models.transactionsModel.certificate#cert2"   etc. (ie standard URI syntax for posting a relationship field in JSON)

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I was just entering in my certificates wrong